# Refactor for Maintainance

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub ButtonVisibilityOnTab()
    Select Case ctl.Parent.Name
        Case "tabGeneral"
            ctl.btnAdd.Visible = True               
        Case "tabSecond"
            ctl.btnAdd.Visible = False                
        Case "tabThird"
            ctl.btnAdd.Visible = False               
        Case Else
            ctl.btnAdd.Visible = False               
    End Select
End Sub
```

How can I optimize/refactor the above code.

I have an app with 3 tabs and a common user control between them. I want to enable the visibility for a add button I have only the first tab.

How can I optimize the code so that in the future if can avoid another case if the user control is reused.

Should I pass the bool value with the tab control name to accomplish that. 
or would an array of controls be logical as a pass in value for the method..

Comment: Very simple, just remove cases for tabSecond and tabThird and keep the default value only once there in Else section.

Comment: The Visibility property could be data bound such that you would not need the switch statement

Comment: Do you foresee any instances where this add button will need to be used on any new tabs in the future?

Comment: Ok good idea , that is what I did to clean it up if and else. Jan, that was my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of these statement to do, you could create a setting class.

```
Class Settings
    Public Property CanAdd As Boolean
End Class
```

This class would be inside each tabs and each tabs would set their own values. Then, your button visibility function would look at the current tab settings.

```
Public Sub ButtonVisibilityOnTab()
    ctl.btnAdd.Visible = ctl.Parent.Setting.CanAdd
End Sub
```

You could then implement on all your tab an interface that handle the settings. Your function would then look like.

```
Public Sub ButtonVisibilityOnTab()
    ctl.btnAdd.Visible = CType(ctl.Parent, ISomeInterface).Setting.CanAdd
End Sub
```

Comment: This is taking a a step forward. I like the idea. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

AS your code is written, it can be simplified to

```
 Public Sub ButtonVisibilityOnTab()
     ctl.btnAdd.Visible = (ctl.Parent.Name.ToLower().Equals("tabgeneral"))
 End Sub
```

Or more generically,

```
 Public Sub ButtonVisibilityOnTab(CompareTo as String)
     ctl.btnAdd.Visible = (ctl.Parent.Name.ToLower().Equals(CompareTo.ToLower()))
 End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing an '=' sign in your equality check.

Comment: double equals in VB.Net ??

Comment: He had it right the first time: `==` is a C# (and family) thing, not VB. I recommend opting for .Equals() in this situation, to avoid the ambiguity

Comment: One thing to mention, while this makes the current scenario more concise, I don't know that it "optimizes" the code, since if the control is ever needed on an additional tab, the code would need to be changed. I got the impression that the OP was looking for something more along these lines.

Comment: In that case, I'd have an array with the names of "true" tabs, and check whether the array Contains() the control name.

Comment: Thanks that's true on one equal sign.

Comment: I guess you might have misread my question. But still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, and I started passing the control Name as a parameter.

```
Private Sub ButtonVisibilityOnTab(controlName As String, blnShowOrNot As Boolean)
    If _ctl.Parent.Name = controlName Then
        _ctl.btnAdd.Visible = blnShowOrNot            
    Else
        _ctl.btnAdd.Visible = Not (blnShowOrNot)          
    End If
End Sub
```